# Difference between homo sapiens and homo sapiens sapiens?

Tags: etymology, errors

I know the Latin *homo* means ["human being" or "man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo), while *sapiens* means ["wise"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom). So, *homo sapiens* means "wise man." What does our subspecies, *homo sapiens sapiens*, mean? Is it, "wise man who knows?"

Comment: This is more of a biology question than it is an English one.

Comment: The question is really, i think, about the **rationale** behind the naming of the subspecies, rather than the actual biology.  ie, what did the person who came up with "homo sapiens sapiens" mean by having two "sapiens" in there?

Comment: I'm not concerned with the biology of the situation. I just want to know, from a Latin language standpoint, what *homo sapiens sapiens* means. Exactly right, @MaxWilliams.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker in comments explained that his question is not about English at all but rather about Latin.

Comment: I disagree that the question is about Latin. It is about scientific terminology which is universally used in English and all languages.  Haggis Pouch's answer is correct.

Comment: The western gorilla is Gorilla gorilla. The Western lowland gorilla is Gorilla gorilla gorilla. It doesn't mean that Gorilla gorilla gorilla is more gorilla-like than Gorilla gorilla. Similarly, Homo neanderthalensis was thought to be a distinct species from homo sapiens but DNA testing shows Neanderthal DNA in non-Africans. So Homo neanderthalensis is Homo sapiens Neanderthalensis and Homo sapiens needs an additional specifier, and the answer of Haggis Pouch explains why it is  sapiens repeated.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens

"Modern humans are the subspecies Homo sapiens sapiens, which differentiates them from what has been argued to be their direct ancestor, Homo sapiens idaltu."

"Idaltu" is from the Saho-Afar word meaning "elder" or "first born".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens_idaltu

I think in this sense the double-barrelled "sapiens sapiens" really just means "more wise than the single sapiens".

I think this is really an example of a controversy within speciation/naming.  There are lots of questions to answer:  are Homo sapiens sapiens actually the same species as Homo sapiens idaltu?   How do we know how intelligent our predecessors really were?  Does being more intelligent actually make you a different species?  Since we can't get one of the latter to try to have a child with a modern human, and we don't have their genome, we may never know.  Information on human predecessors is pretty thin on the ground.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you are assuming that scientists intend species names to have literal meaning in a way that they often don't. *"Homo sapiens sapiens"* isn't a well-formed Latin phrase. There is nothing for the extra *"sapiens"* to modify. The question of what the name means in Latin mistakenly assumes that it **does** mean something in Latin.

The lack of meaning isn't at all odd, because the purpose of the repeated word isn't to further describe the subspecies, but rather to identify it in accordance with zoological naming conventions as the subspecies originally identified as constituting the species. So, the repeated *"sapiens"* isn't in the term because of its meaning.  *"Homo sapiens sapiens"* is intended to convey (and does, to those who know the convention) "the subspecies originally regarded as the species *Homo sapiens."* [Wikipedia on Subspecies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspecies), [The full official zoological naming convention](http://www.iczn.org/iczn/index.jsp)

So, to use an example from Wikipedia, the *Motacilla alba alba* is the kind of wagtail that was first identified as belonging to the species *Motacilla alba.* It isn't any whiter than other white wagtails.

Keep in mind, too, that biological names often include elements never intended to describe fauna or flora. The 'Latinized' names of well-known people from Hitler to Shakira appear in the names of various biological categories without contributing anything to the meaning of their names.

In summary, there is no accurate, meaningful translation of *"Homo sapiens sapiens"* because it isn't (and wasn't intended to be) a meaningful Latin phrase. So, the question as asked rests on a confusion. One might as well ask what "wise human wise" means beyond "wise human."

Comment: Very good answer, and as far as I can tell (this is not my field), correct.